# JSON.parse Issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, parsing, firefox

so, I am working on a website for a client, a friend of mine.
He sells geckos, and he has made a website for himself, and his sales partner, and I am doing a lot of javascript work for him, IE AJAX, etc... Well, I got to the available lizard page for him, and I am making a sort of dynamic gecko selection system. The way this script is supposed to work is, fetch a JSON file ([here](http://www.texaslizardconnection.com/components/lizards.json)) which is perfectly good JSON, and then parse the values in to multiselects. I'm using the jQuery.get function to do this. All goes well until I try parsing the JSON data, and the browser, firefox, throws the error "Syntax Error: JSON.parse", and chromium throws the error "Unexpected Token", the problem also occurred with
The error is thrown on line 219 of js.js,

```
jQuery.parseJSON().
```

the issues are in the function drawCat(data), the page this code is in use on is [Here](http://www.texaslizardconnection.com/#newavailable)

I hope that this is a quality question, I'm really quite tired to be coding right now, it pretty late.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think its valid, there's a bunch of missing commas part way down the file, screenshot attached as no line numbering.[image]

Comment: ps. New Zealanders will cause you less headaches than Australians!

Comment: how could I have not noticed it. What happpened was, I coppy/pasted the same section, and then noticed it needed commas, so I put commas in, and thought that I had done them all. Let me fix this, and I'll get back to you about it

Answer (score 2):

Actually that is not valid JSON. It's easy to check at http://jsonlint.com/. The error is that the root should be either one JSON object or an array. Now you have several JSON objects as roots.

**Update**: Danjah is also correct. After you fix this the problem he highlights will also cause invalid JSON. so you need to fix both.